# Explanation of why $\int \sin^2 x\cos^2 x\; dx = 1/3 \sin^3 x - 2/5 \sin^5 x + 1/7 \sin^7 x +c$

Tags: calculus, integration

> verify the solution
>   $$\int \sin^2 x\cos^5 x\; dx = 1/3 \sin^3 x - 2/5 \sin^5 x + 1/7 \sin^7 x +c$$

I have hit this in my book and can't work it out. Does anyone have any ideas or a walk-through that might help?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense; you can't integrate an equation. Do you perhaps want to ask for an explanation of$$\int\sin^2 x\cos^2 x\; dx = 1/3 \sin^3 x - 2/5 \sin^5 x + 1/7 \sin^7 x +c$$

Comment: Yeah sorry heads all over the place today.

Comment: @1ftw1, have you observed that the derivative the Right Hand Side is $\sin^2x\cos^5x?$

Comment: $$I=\int \sin^2x\cos^5xdx=\int \sin^2x\cos^4x\cdot\cos xdx=\int \sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)^2
\cdot\cos xdx$$


Putting $\sin x=u,\cos xdx=du$

$$\implies I=\int u^2(1-u^2)^2du=\int(u^6-2u^4+u^2)du =\frac{u^7}7-\frac25\cdot u^5+\frac{u^3}3+C$$
$$=\frac{\sin^7x}7-\frac25\cdot\sin^5x+\frac{\sin^3x}3+C$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

1) $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x),$$

2) $$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2} \implies \sin^2(2x)=\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{2}. $$

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to start from the right hand side. Derive to get:
$$ (\sin^2 x - 2\sin^4 x + \sin^6 x)\cos x$$
Note that this is just:
$$(\sin x - \sin^3 x)^2\cos x=\sin^2 x(1-\sin^2x)^2\cos x=\sin^2 x\cos^5x$$
So, it seems you are missing a couple of powers of $\cos x$ in the integral..

Comment: $$\frac{d\sin^nx }{dx}=n\sin^{n-1}x\cos x,$$ right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - embarrassing, fixed. It would appear the statement in question is wrong as well.

Comment: have you noticed my comment in the Question?